# A manga about a girl who works in a flower shop, lover has private beach house and gives her his earring

Tags: kiss-hug

I know bits of it but I still have no luck in finding it!

It starts off with a girl who works at a flower shop. She sees a boy and he immediately makes her his lover. (I think he was a demon).

In one of the chapters, the boy is going back to his home so he can finish his work. He takes her to his private beach house, where he makes love to the girl and she allows it. The next day, they get dressed and he notices how much he changed her. When they get to the airport, he gives her his earring he always wears and tells her that he will come back for her, then he kisses her and leaves.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [**Kiss/Hug**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=12453)?

The girls works in a flower shop that belongs to the family. The scene you're describing resembles one of the last few chapters where he has to go to England for some work he does.

**Synopsis**

> Ryuu, a super-business-like transfer student from England with black hair and blue eyes just arrived! During the night of the Tanabata festival, Ryuu and Yukino became attracted to each other at first sight. He then declares, "You will be mine!" This brought confusion to Yukino, who has zero experience in love. But could she actually be falling in love?